# using Foreach to make a table

Tags: foreach, json

Im new to PHP and I made this to display to my website what has been uploaded in the fdpp portal

```
<?php $resp = file_get_contents("http://fdpp.blgs.gov.ph/api/documents?source=datatable&sSearch=kalinga"); 
$clean = json_decode($resp);

print_r($clean); ?>
```

this is the result :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [iTotalRecords] => 130035
    [iTotalDisplayRecords] => 879
    [sEcho] => 0
    [aaData] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [lgu] => <a href=' http://fdpp.blgs.gov.ph/documents/view/129293'>CAR<br/>Kalinga<br />Balbalan</a>
                    [document] => <a href=' http://fdpp.blgs.gov.ph/documents/view/129293'>Local Disaster Risk Reduction and Management Fund Utilization (LDRRMF)</a>
                    [period] => Quarter 1 2014
                    [status] => Required &bull; SUBMITTED 
                    [desc] => The atng.
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [lgu] => <a href=' http://fdpp.blgs.gov.ph/documents/view/129188'>CAR<br/>Kalinga<br />Balbalan</a>
                    [document] => <a href=' http://fdpp.blgs.gov.ph/documents/view/129188'>Manpower Complement</a>
                    [period] => Quarter 1 2014
                    [status] => Required &bull; SUBMITTED 
                    [desc] => The file ag.
                )
```

what shall I add to my code to put this in a table with column name lgu, document, period? I tried reading foreach manual but I cant figure it out can someone help me?

Comment: Without your attempts and telling us where you are stuck it is pretty much impossible to help you.

Comment: As clarification, it appears he's trying to use the jQuery DataTables library with server side processing. [Here's an example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with PeeHaa (+1) with not enough information given, but I'm going to attempt to help you out.

The following assumptions were made:

1. You have a local MySQL DB named "testdb"
2. You have the PDO extension installed
3. In "testdb", you have a table named "test_table" with 4
   columns (id, lgu, document, period)

First, you need to set the second parameter in `json_decode` to true to return an associative array rather than an object ([PHP: json_decode)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

So, based upon the limited information, here is a working version:

```
<?php
$resp = file_get_contents("http://fdpp.blgs.gov.ph/api/documents?source=datatable&sSearch=kalinga");
$clean = json_decode($resp,true);

// Open connection to your MySQL DB
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'username', 'password');

// Parse the now-associative array and insert into table
foreach($clean['aaData'] as $doc){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test_table(lgu,document,period) VALUES(:lgu,:document,:period)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':lgu' => $doc['lgu'], ':document' => $doc['document'], ':period' => $doc['period']));
}
?>
```

You should really provide some more information for a more exact answer.

But, this should set you in the right direction.